# SQL query to insert a new column by adding the values in one column using distinct features

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct-values

I have table with three columns (a,b,c), i need to create a new column 'd', by using the distinct features of columns a and b.

```
a  b  c
1  p  2
1  p  3 
2  q  4
1  q  2
2  r  4
2  r  2
1  p  2
```

I need the answer as below, where d is the sum of the unique column of a and b

```
a b c d
1 p 2 7
1 p 3 7
2 q 4 4
1 q 2 2
2 r 4 6
2 r 2 6
1 p 2 7
```

The result of the column d is,

for distinct(a & b),
    then, add the values of c.
And then insert the valuesin the column d (matching the distinct values)

Comment: What's your dbms

Comment: And explain the logic for the output, eg how is 1+p=7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `SUM` and `group by` `a` and `b` columns in subquery, then self `join`

**TestDLL**

```
create table t(
   a int,
   b varchar(5),
   c int
);

insert into t values (1,'p',2);
insert into t values (1,'p',3);
insert into t values (2,'q',4);
insert into t values (1,'q',2);
insert into t values (2,'r',4);
insert into t values (2,'r',2);
insert into t values (1,'p',2);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.d 
FROM T t1 INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a,b,SUM(c) d
    FROM T
    GROUP BY a,b
) t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.b=t2.b
```

**[Results]**:

```
| a | b | c | d |
|---|---|---|---|
| 1 | p | 2 | 7 |
| 1 | p | 3 | 7 |
| 2 | q | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | q | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | r | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | r | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | p | 2 | 7 |
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a6fa/1)

Comment: Thank you so much D-Shih.. Also, can i ask if its possible to sum the values for a interval of 2.

Comment: What's your mean `interval of 2`? Could you give me some example? thank

Comment: For example: 

a  b c d
1  p 2 5 /
1  p 3 5 /
1  p 4 6 /
1  p 2 6 /

Something similar to this. adding the values at the interval of 2 for the distinct values

Comment: What's your dbms? sql-server or mysql or another?

Comment: My dbms is mysql.

Comment: If your mysql version didn't support windows function that will be hard to do it:(

Comment: Anyway thank you.. I will check out the other possibilities. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the window function for SUM is supported

```
select a, b, c, sum(c) over (partition by a, b) as d
from yourtable
```

Comment: Can you explain me in detail. I am new to sql.  Is it possible to add values with the distinct interval of 2? I use mysql 5.7

Comment: @Sara If you really need that with the interval of 2. Then I'll suggest to post another question for it. It's a more tricky requirement. But this time make sure that you tag that question with MySql.  And mention the version. Because you wouldn't want something that only works in MySql 8.x.

Answer (score 0):

use `case when` and create your other column if generated  value is constant

```
 select a,b,c, case when a=1  and b='p'  then 7
    when a=2 and b='q' then 4
    when a=2 and b='r' then 6
    when a=1 and b='q' then 2 else '' end as d from
    your_table
```

But it seems to me you need group sum of a,b as a 4th column d , so
you can do like below

```
select t1.a,t1.b,t1.c,t2.d from yourtable t1
inner join
(select a,b ,sum(c) as d from your table group by a,b) as t2
on t1.a=t2.a and t1.b=t2.b
```